# SQL - Join with with multi criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I've 3 tables :

**recipe**               : id - name

**criteria**             : id - name

**recipe_has_criterias** : id - id_recipe - id_criteria

For example, in **recipe_has_criterias** :

1 - 1 - 1

2 - 1 - 2

3 - 2 - 1

I want to get recipe with criteria 1 and 2. (here recipe with id 1)

How can I do this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: But `recipe with id 1` is associated with `1 and 2` in the given example.

Comment: Both criteria 2 and 3 required? (Or just one of them, or both.)

Comment: answer on @AbhikChakraborty query and also let us know what fields you required as may be you can get data from single table or 2 or 3 as per your required data.

Comment: My bad, I edited the question. It's both required

Answer (score 1):

```
select r.name
from recipe r
join recipe_has_criterias rc on r.id = rc.id_recipe
where rc.id_criteria in (2,3)
group by r.name
having count(distinct rc.id_criteria) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*,b.*,c.*
from recipe_has_criterias a
inner join recipe b
on b.id=a.id_recipe
inner join criteria c
on c.id=a. id_criteria and a. id_criteria in(2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing 2 joins, one for each criteria:-

```
SELECT r.name
FROM recipe r
INNER JOIN recipe_has_criteria rc1
ON r.id = rc1.id_recipe
INNER JOIN recipe_has_criteria rc2
ON r.id = rc2.id_recipe
WHERE rc1.id_criteria = 2
AND rc2.id_criteria = 3
```

Comment: here i am not seeing any benefit of join recipe_has_criteria table 2 times.

Comment: One for each of the required criteria, and saves using any aggregate functions.

Comment: if join table single time and criteria in (2,3)..will it produce different results.

Comment: Not if a aggregate function is used to check that 2 rows are returned